# Send code html from page page asp to page aspx for System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I am trying to send through System.Net.Mail from my server.
To do this I have created a page aspx, that however I don't directly call, in how much my site is realized in classical asp.
To make this self I go to use the object MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

```
    file= "http://www.myserver.net/SendGridMail.aspx"
             DataToSend="mailTo="& dest &"&Text="& server.HTMLEncode(testo) &"&Object="& server.HTMLEncode(oggetto) &"&bcc="& bcc &"&mailFrom="& from  &"&nameFrom=Pippo.Fr" 

   Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objXmlHttp.Open "POST", file, False
   objXmlHttp.send DataToSend
```

In the page ASPX I recall with a request the variables and I pass her to the object MailMessage.

The problems that I have are these.
I don't succeed in sending the methods from the page asp with the object send. I don't receive error but the email not games, I think that it doesn't receive the data.

```
            Set objXmlHttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
            objXmlHttp.Open "POST", file, False


            file = "http://www.myserver.net/Mail.aspx?mailTo="& dest &"&Text="& server.HTMLEncode(testo) &"&Object="& server.HTMLEncode(oggetto) &"&bcc="& bcc &"&mailFrom="& from  &"&nameFrom=Pippo.Fr"
```

If I send everything through querystring I don't succeed in inserting a text html

code page aspx

```
            string mailTo = Request["mailTo"]; 
            string mailFrom = Request["mailFrom"];
            string nameFrom = Request["nameFrom"];
            string Object = Request["Object"];
            string Text = Request["Text"];
            string bcc = Request["bcc"];



            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();

            // To
            mailMsg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));

            // From
            mailMsg.From = new MailAddress(mailFrom, nameFrom);

            if (bcc != "")
            {
                mailMsg.Bcc.Add(bcc);
            }

            // Subject and multipart/alternative Body
            mailMsg.Subject = Object;

            mailMsg.Body = Text
```

Can someone help me?
I want to send some code html in the text and if it is possible to send the data from the page asp on post and not in querystring.
Thanks

Comment: What's the actual URL being generated here?  It's probably a bit long of a URL, and it may easily contain a whole lot of things which make it an invalid URL.  Does `server.HTMLEncode()` *HTML*-encode the text, or *URL*-encode the text?  They're two very different things, and the latter is what would be needed.

Comment: @David if I use urlEncode I receive this error: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client . if I use htmlEncode I don't get the request. if I don't put the request void it works but only if I insert text and not html.